# How to make Labels and TextFields reposition based on size of window

Tags: javafx, label, textfield, maximize

I have a few textfields and Labels in my fxml file. All of them lie on an Anchor Pane. While the TableViews get repositioned correctly when I maximize the Pane, labels and Text Fields dont change position and hence all of them look out of sync. Any clues will be helpful.

Here is the code to simulate the problem. When you maximize the fxml the heading goes out of whack.

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"  fx:controller="testbed.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
    <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.14715719063545152" layoutX="175.0" layoutY="74.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <items>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
           <children>
              <Label layoutX="234.0" layoutY="32.0" text="MAIN HEADING ">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="18.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
           <children>
              <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.4949664429530201" layoutX="52.0" layoutY="140.0" prefHeight="507.0" prefWidth="598.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                <items>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </items>
              </SplitPane>
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </items>
  </SplitPane>
</children>
```

Comment: An `AnchorPane` is pretty much designed to have the position of its child nodes hard coded - at least in relation to the edges. It's probably the layout pane I use the least. You probably want a different layout pane. It would help a lot if you could show what you are getting, what you want that is different, and post your code.

Comment: Hi James, Added FXMLFile to simulate the problem. Which pane would you suggest as base?

Comment: Since Anchorpane was coming default, I started using it.Looks BorderPane is what I need. It works well with it. I guess I just need to reduce the left and right panes if I want to utilise the rest of the area to the maximum. Or can we have anchorpane work someway?